# How to connect to another VNC desktop?

Tags: linux, vnc, vnc-server

In ubuntu I use the command 'vncserver -geometry 1920x1080' to start a vncserver. It then reports that 'my_vncserver:1' started.

When I do the same command again, it reports that 'my_vncserver:2' started.

In my VNC viewer, I would like to connect to this second server, how do I do this? The way I connect to the first vncserver is just by connecting to -my_ip-:5901. But how do I specify that I want to connect to the other vnc server?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

VNC uses TCP port 5900+n for display number n.

- DISPLAY=:0 -> port 5900
- DISPLAY=:1 -> port 5901
- and in your case, DISPLAY=:2 -> port 5902

Comment: Excellent! Thank you.